# standalone mysql 5.7 instance on preemptible node, which settings can make mysql run in the most fault-tolerant way possible?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Simplifying, I have a **standalone mysql instance** running on a docker container hosted on a **preemptible node**.
That means that at least ever 24 hours, the underlying node is killed, and a clean shutdown is never guaranteed.

Before going this route, I tested the setup by simulating this scenario on different loads, also write operations, and killing the underlying nodes by triggering a kernel panic: no issues even after thousands of restarts.

On the real world, from time to time - let's say once a month over 3000 mysql instances - a DB gets corrupted, and it needs recovery (force recovery, full dump, reload of the dump).

What is the best set of options I could configure to make sure mysql operates in a way where, even with frequent kills of the server, it will not write inconsistent data? Sacrificing performance is not an issue.

This is the config it currently has (mysql is running on docker, so *aio = OFF*):

```
max_connections = 60
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
tmp_table_size = 4M
key_buffer_size = 8M
query_cache_size = 4M
query_cache_limit = 512K
thread_stack = 128K
performance_schema = 0
show_compatibility_56 = 1
innodb-use-native-aio = OFF
```

**Edit: I am looking for my.cfg settings to make mysql as crash-proof as possible, not architectural solutions**

Comment: no system likes when it gets suddenly shutdown without proper procedures, get a clean copy of your daza everytime the docker starts or switch the provider

Comment: What's your setting of `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`?

Comment: @nbk obviously that's not an option

Comment: @mustaccio it is = 1

Comment: I doubt there's much you can do on the MySQL side beyond that -- you cannot configure a dinosaur to withstand an asteroid impact. OTOH, I have yet to see a preemption mechanism that cannot be configured to perform graceful shutdown of its victims, so consider looking in that direction.

Comment: @mustaccio well... mysql is clearly designed to withstand a crash, in fact the issue happens once every few months on more than 3 thousands instances, so it means it happens approximately every 3000*30days*3 months crashes. The point is, if there is some further change to sacrifice some performance for that extra tiny bit of fault tolerance.

Comment: The problem is outside MySQL control. All it can do is call `fsync()` on transaction commit, but that doesn't mean the data are indeed persisted to disk -- there are a couple of extra layers between the database container kernel and the actual hardware: storage is virtualilzed by the container host, and then there's probably a network-attached block storage with a TCP stack and its own cache, so there is always a chance data will be lost somewhere on its way to disk, unless you have full knowledge of and control over the entire infrastructure stack.